# Laravel query where column contains one or more keywords in array

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of keywords:

```
arr = ["puppy", "kitty", "baby"];
```

I want to have Laravel Eloquent query where **id < 20** and that 'subject' has one or more of the array values.

Not sure how to write this. I tried foreach but didn't work:

```
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
            $firstPageTopics = Article::where('id', '<', 20)->where('type', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the loop inside the `closure` of a `where` and use the `orWhere` method to chain several conditional where's together.

```
Article::where('id', '<', 20)
->where(function ($q) use ($keywords) {
    collect($keywords)->each(function ($keyword) use ($q) {
      $q->orWhere('type', 'like', '%'. $keyword .'%');
    });
})->get();
```

Comment: Can you explain how it works? I tried to figure it out on my own but I'm confused fro the function inside the function and can't find docs on collect function.